# Need help with Ubuntu 22.04 top bar

Tags: icons, themes, gnome-shell, bug-reporting, desktop-icons

I was messing around with some Mac themes and messed up.

I defaulted the Ubuntu look but the top bar still looks the same, with the Apple logo on the left and all. Also, I have two bugged desktop icons, they aren't clickable.

I have disabled all the extensions.

Ubuntu 22.04

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRgfB.jpg

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: The solution to these kinds of problems is to undo what you did. When tinkering it's important to keep a record of what you did so you can undo them when something goes wrong. Hopefully you kept track of what you did. Otherwise, if you can't tell us what you did that caused the problem, it's unlikely we can tell you how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mess with your desktop, it is difficult to hint how to precisely unmess it. You may try resetting the settings to factory defaults to see if this solves the issue.

- Try first resetting everything related to the desktop.

  ```
  dconf reset -f /org/gnome/desktop/wm/
  dconf reset -f /org/gnome/gnome-session/
  dconf reset -f /org/gnome/shell/
  dconf reset -f /org/gnome/mutter/
  dconf reset -f /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-dock/
  ```

Log back out then back in before concluding whether it works.

- If it did not work, you can also try a reset of all dconf settings related to gnome:

  ```
  dconf reset -f /org/gnome/
  ```
- or any dconf settings whatsoever:

  ```
  dconf reset -f /
  ```
- If that still does not work, you can reset your entire account. Log in to a recovery prompt with root permissions, rename your original home directory, create an empty one, copy the few files in `/etc/skel` over to it, and change ownership (user and group) to your account. Login in will give you a factory default account with factory default files. You can then easily move your user data back over from the old home directory to the new one.

Comment: Thank you very much, the first fix worked!

Comment: Thank you for the feedback!